# C# Как десериализовать это в переменные?

Tags: c#, ajax, json

Как десериализовать это в переменные?C#.Дайте пример плиз,уже 2ой день не получается ничего и с библиотекой JSON.NET

```
{"messages":[{"text":"TEXT MESSAGE","channel":"main":"from":"USERNAME","fromid":651765,"t":1379970985409,"tc":"f16d7e"}}}
```

Comment: ничего удивительного, приведённая строка - это не валидный json, а лишь отдалённыя пародия:

    {
        "messages":
            [
                "text":    "TEXT MESSAGE",
                "channel": "main":
                "from":    "USERNAME",
                "fromid":  651765,
                "t":       1379970985409,
                "tc":      "f16d7e"
            }
    }
    }

Comment: Не-не, никаких регулярных выражений для рекурсивных языков!

А откуда взялась строка? Там и правда невалидный JSON, настучите источнику по голове.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В указанном в вопрое JSON есть ошибки. Чтобы их исправить надо:
1) заменить `}}}` на `}]}`
2) заменить `"main":"from"` на `"main","from"`

К проекту подключите `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` (PM> Install-Package [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/))

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jo = JObject.Parse(str);
```